# Is a foreach loop on $_GET a good way to apply htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php, foreach, htmlspecialchars

I'm wondering if there is a significant downside to using the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET)){
foreach($_GET as $v){
    $v = htmlspecialchars($v);
}
}
```

I realize that it probably isn't necessary to use htmlspecialchars on each variable. Anyone know offhand if this is good to do?

UPDATE:

Because I don't think my above code would work, I'm updating this with the code that I'm using (despite the negativity towards the suggestions). :)

```
if(isset($_GET)){
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v){
    $_GET[$k] = htmlspecialchars($v);
}
}
```

Comment: '$v' will not exist once the foreach loop ends...

Comment: Only apply htmlspecialchars() when you're about to put the text into (or for) an HTML page. There's no point in processing it beforehand, because if you end up using the data for some OTHER purpose, you'll just have to undo the escaping anyways.

Comment: If `$_GET` contains an multi-dimensional array it won't be escaped.

Comment: Good point on the multi-dimensional array.  I won't have any.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This totally depends on what you want to do.

In general, the answer is "no", and you should only escape data specifically for their intended purpose. Randomly escaping data without purpose isn't helping, and it just causes further confusion, as you have to keep track of what's been escaped and how.

In short, keep your data stored raw, and escape it specifically for its intended use *when* you use it:

- for HTML output, use `htmlentities()`.
- for shell command names, use `escapeshellcmd()`.
- for shell arguments, use `escapeshellarg()`.
- for building a GET URL string, use `urlencode()` on the parameter values.
- for database queries, use the respective database escape mechanism (or prepared statements).

This reasoning applies recursively. So if you want to write a link to a GET URL to the HTML output, it'd be something like this:

```
echo "<a href=" . htmlentities("$url?q=" . urlencode($var)) . ">click</a>";
```

It'd be terrible if at that point you'd have to remember if `$var` had already previously been escaped, and how.

Comment: For this page, I'm using every variable.  It's a form, and I want it to show the user what they entered, after they submit it.  The problem is that I've already created the form, and only now am I thinking about securing it with htmlspecialchars... :)

Comment: Security as an afterthought sounds like a bad omen... so does "proper design as an afterthought". Correct escaping is an integral part of the program design. Hm. If you want to store the HTML-escaped variables, you should probably make a new array specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Not really a big deal for this project, which is why I was so nonchalant about it.  It's just a basic (probably never-to-be-used) form, asking for names, email addresses, and other personal information.  I just wanted to make sure I disabled the ability to tamper with it.

Answer (score 3):

Blanket escaping isn't necessary, and it's possibly harmful to the data. Don't do it.

Apply `htmlspecialchars()` only to data that you are about to output in a HTML page - ideally immediately before, or directly when you output it.

Comment: Seconded on formatting your query data BEFORE it gets sent. Especially if it's $_GET data.

Comment: I'm outputting every variable in $_GET.  I wanted to blanket it mostly because I've already created the site, and forgot to use htmlspecialchars when outputting.  I'm kind of new to the PHP thing. :)

Comment: @bozdoz mm, better get used to escaping before outputting. Blanket escaping will create other problems later!

Comment: What problems would it create?  For example?

Comment: @bozdoz well, any `< > " '` would be converted into `&lt; &gt; &quot; and &{can't remember right now};`, which is not what you want if you want to insert the data into a database for example

Comment: I don't though.  I just want the users to see what they entered in the form.  Just basic personal info like names, numbers, addresses.  I don't think it's going to be a problem.  Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @bozdoz mmmm yeah, but at some point, you will want to do more than that, and then your blanket sanitation will be useless. I'd recommend doing it right from the start - but for what you need it now, it would be okay.

Answer (score 1):

It won't affect numbers, but it can backfire for string parameters which are not intended to be put in HTML code.

You have to treat each key different depending on its meaning. Possibility of generalization also depends on your application.

Comment: It's a pretty basic form.  Really just asking for names, locations, and email addresses.

Comment: Remove securing from `$_GET` array and add it one by one to every string field whenever it gets echoed to HTML or used in a url. That's the way, no generalization :-)

Comment: It would take too long for my liking.  Especially since I want to output every single variable. I'd rather do them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it won't work. You need to make `$v` a reference, and it breaks for anything requiring recursion (`$_GET['array'][0]`, for example).

```
if(isset($_GET)) {
  foreach($_GET as &$v) {
    $v = htmlspecialchars($v);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're right.  But I also think my entire code wouldn't work, at second look.  I think it probably needs to be ($_GET as $k=>$v){ $_GET[$k] = htmlspecialchars($v); }

Comment: That does the same thing as the reference (the ampersand before $v) does.